# How to show items in list of strings in textviews dynamically

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to show the items in my list to textviews.

The wordslist.java is

```
public class WordsList {
```

```
List<String> set1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("sane", "said",
        "dean", "ideas", "deans", "anise", "naiades", "sand", "aide",
        "dais", "saned", "aside", "sedan", "idea", "aids", "ands",
        "naiad", "aides", "naiads"));
// 19 words

List<String> set2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("doer", "lord",
        "rode", "role", "drool", "older", "flooder", "odor", "lore",
        "rood", "fore", "rodeo", "folder", "floored", "door", "roof",
        "redo", "ford", "floor", "roofed"));
// 20 words
List<String> set3 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("mead", "dale",
        "lead", "dual", "lamed", "mauled", "medulla", "lade", "male",
        "alum", "maul", "mall", "ladle", "malled", "dame", "made", "lame",
        "laud", "meal", "medal", "allude"));
// 21 words
```

Actually these are the answers of the puzzle, there about 25 puzzles(from set1 to set 25)

When the user clicks give Up. it goes to gameover activity in that activity i have button ' show missed words' ,now when this button is pressed , i want to show the items in the corresponding list.

for showing the words  i created a xml layout with some textviews.

```
LinearLayout myLayout;
    myLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tvLayout);
               myTextViewList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < myLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
            if (myLayout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
                myTextViewList.add((TextView) myLayout.getChildAt(i));
```

and when to set text

```
WordsList w = new WordsList();
    TextView tv =    myTextViewList.get(counter);
                tv.setText(w.set1);
```

Here is my logcat

```
 01-28 20:29:42.105  11122-11122/rpa.screening.spellathon E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rpa.screening.spellathon, PID: 11122
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at rpa.screening.spellathon.GameOver_Screen$2.onClick(GameOver_Screen.java:44)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4487)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18746)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

EDIT 2 :
Gameover_screen

```
missedWords.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent iin = getIntent();
            Bundle b = iin.getExtras();


            if (b != null) {

                String passed_score = (String) b.get("score");
                displayScore.setText(passed_score);
                int passed_set = (int) b.get("set"); // line 44
                String s = Integer.valueOf(passed_set).toString();


                Intent ii = new Intent(GameOver_Screen.this, MissedWords.class);
                ii.putExtra("sEt", s);
                startActivity(ii);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Its like a Spellathon type app.

Comment: Please be clear what do you want to ask !

Comment: tell us where Your problem is. What You´ve tried and what doesn´t work...

Comment: i want to show the items in the list in textviews

Comment: When i clicked show missed words it shows null pointer error@Opiatefuchs

Comment: it will be better to post the logcat. I have some assumption but without seeing how You do this completely its only speculative

Comment: Added logcat, check now @Opiatefuchs

Comment: It´s like I thought, something is not initialized. Show us what in Your GameOver_Screen.java class is in line 44.

Comment: Why not using `ListView`  or `RecyclerView`

Comment: its the value passed from mainactivity telling about which set is selected@Opiatefuchs

Comment: Are you sure that your bundle contains the an Object with "set" as key? you can use *b.containsKey("set");* to check that.
Notice that you can just use *b.getInt("set");* instead of  *(int) b.get("set");*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED MY QUESTION.

The actual problem is here,

```
tv.setText(w.set1);
```

but when i changed it to,

```
String set1 = w.set1.get(i);
tv.setText(set1);
```

the problem solved.